# Are time-of-flight cameras like the swissranger affected by outdoor fog?

Tags: mobile-robot, cameras

I'm looking to build an outdoor robot and I need to know if [time-of-flight cameras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_camera) like the [SwissRanger™ SR4500](http://www.mesa-imaging.ch/swissranger4500.php) work in fog, does anybody have some experiences on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swissranger is a RF-modulated light sources with phase detectors which is one type of time of flight camera. The other type is Range Gated Imager. The Wiki Page for time-of-flight cameras http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_camera  states this for the Range Gated imagers:

"Range gated imagers can also be used in 2D imaging to suppress anything outside a specified distance range, such as to see through fog. A pulsed laser provides illumination, and an optical gate allows light to reach the imager only during the desired time period."

It also states that:

"The ZCam by 3DV Systems is a range-gated system."

Comment: Ok so I should move to a different kind of TOF cameras?
Or wait for the new kinect to be released for PCs?

Comment: You will have to email Microsoft and ask if their new Kinect will do what you require or use one of the other TOF cameras which definatley does as described above. Which camera should I buy is quite a general question though.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Michele what did you end up doing? Also looking for a sensor to do depth-measurement under outdoor lighting conditions.

Comment: The project was suspended, If it will revamp I will go for the Intel's realsense: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/208 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjI5RoFeX2c